Callback function to pass data from Child to Parent in react not working
I am trying to pass data from child to parent component via callback function but somehow, it's not working. What am I doing wrong here? Sharing the code snippets below along with the error message. Any help would be highly appreciated.
App.js
 const [dataFromChild, setDataFromChild] = useState('');
 const handleDataFromChild = (data) => {
    setDataFromChild(data);
  }
  
  function receiveChildData() {
    if (dataFromChild === undefined || dataFromChild.length === 0) {
     return null;
    } else {
      return <div><EmpView onDataFromChild={handleDataFromChild} /></div>;
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          name="select"
          options={data}
          multi
          onChange={handleSelect}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <EmpView
          key={JSON.stringify(nodeData)}
          nodeData={nodeData}
         />
      </div>
       {receiveChildData()}
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;

Emp.js
const EmpView = (nodeData,{onDataFromChild}) => {

    const [nodeDetails, setNodeDetails] = useState([]);
    
    const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
        console.log(item);
        axios.post("./searchEmp", item.id)
            .then((response) => {

                //set the emp nodeDetails
                setNodeDetails(JSON.parse(response.data.nodeDetails));

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    };
    const sendDataToParent=()=>{
        onDataFromChild(nodeDetails)
    }
    
return
(
    <div className='container'>
            <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}></div>
            <ReactSearchAutocomplete
                items={nodeNames}
                onSelect={handleOnSelect}
            />
            <button onClick={sendDataToParent}>Send Data to Parent</button>
            <Graph
                graph={graph}
                options={options}
            />
       </div>
    )
}
export default EmpView;

Error:
onDataFromChild is not a function
TypeError: onDataFromChild is not a function

const EmpView = (nodeData,{onDataFromChild}) => { Components just receive one argument. Did you mean const EmpView = ({ onDataFromChild }) => {?

no, actually there is one more which is being passed from parent to child in the 1st place.  I updated the code.

Ok, then you want const EmpView = ({ nodeData, onDataFromChild }) => {

ok so i did this and it wasn't recognising 'nodeData, then i changed the syntax to (nodeData, onDataFromChild)  and the 1st error is back. So, basically, what I need is passing a variable as well as a callback function as props at the same time.

you still want the above syntax of const EmpView = ({ nodeData, onDataFromChild }) => {, but you also need to pass in a property for nodeData and onDataFromChild in the EmpView component in App.js.  right now, i don't see onDataFromChild being passed in, just nodeData and key.

yes, it's there, being passed from within the function {receiveChildData()}

in the div right above that line you are creating an EmpView with only nodeData and key properties filled in.

not working, apparently by doing this const EmpView = ({ nodeData, onDataFromChild }) => {, the 1st argument i.e nodeData is being recognized.
